# Pickling cv2.CascadeClassifier

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, opencv, cascade-classifier, python

I'm trying to quickly check if cv2.CascasdeClassifier objects can be pickled using a way or another ; as natively they can't:

```
In [1]: import pickle, cv2                                            


In [2]: c = cv2.CascadeClassifier()                                   


In [3]: pickle.dumps(c)                                               

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-3-4523793c002f> in <module>
----> 1 pickle.dumps(c)

TypeError: can't pickle cv2.CascadeClassifier objects

In [4]:
```

Thanks for any pointer/input..